# Anime style movie about mutated people that gain murderous abilities such as projectile-shooting limbs and limbs with blades on the ends

Tags: story-identification, anime, horror

I saw this movie years ago when I was very young (too young to remember much). I can only remember parts of it, it is an animated horror movie, about mutated people that gain murderous abilities such as projectile-shooting limbs, limbs with blades on the ends, ect. due to a virus? parasite? I also think it takes place in the future. (but that might have been my childish brain seeing a police motorcycle and believing it to be high tech)

- There is a graveyard scene in the rain
- A small girl (maybe boy?) mutates and conjoins with their teddy bear towards the end
- There is a "final battle" with a giant mutant that ends with a big explosion and helicopter escape
- Towards the beginning a mutant with a "gun" for a hand shoots a police officer

Anything that could help me find the name of this movie is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this, and did you watch it on TV, online, or on home media? If on TV, do recall which channel you might've seen it on?

Comment: This sounds like you watched Akira and then watched Elfen Lied straight away afterwards.

Comment: can't believe you can forget something as iconic as Akira

Comment: Elfen Lied - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yxi0cqs-AmQ - WARNING. DEEPLY NFSW

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is most definitely '[Sin: The Movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sin:_The_Movie)'

Everything you describe matches what I remember from the video game anime adaptation:

- The graveyard scene in the beginning of the movie where it is raining.
- The story revolves around a small girl who has a teddy bear
- She is experimented on by SinTek later in the film making her a mutant
- There is a big fight at the end with a helicopter and explosions.
- In the beginning of the film a character named J.D. is killed by a mutant in the sewers (hence the funeral scene)

Comment: Good one. Welcome Dave, please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to our odd ways. This seems so much more apt than Akira. Enjoy the site.

Answer (score 6):

Could this be [Akira](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094625/)? A virus causes a boy to go insane and develop psychic weaponry. There's also a teddy bear scene and an iconic final fight with a big explosion.